# Would nhibernate be used in large scale projects like say facebook? (for arguments sake)

Tags: nhibernate, facebook

For those who know the inner workings of nhibernate, do you think a large scale web application like say facebook/myspace would use nhibernate?

Or is nhibernate well suited for more low traffic sites like company sites etc? i.e. not enterprise ready because of its chatty nature?

Answer (score 9):

NHibernate is not chatty at all. About scalability, there was already a [question on NH's groups](http://groups.google.com.ar/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/1de495362e5b15ba/c43ccb138be737be), which was more about the complexity of the database then traffic, but might still be interesting for you.

Even if there are always complaint's about unnecessary queries on every ORM, because of the generic nature of an ORM, it doesn't mean that it is chatty. On the other hand it optimizes situations where it would be too complex to optimize in hand-written DAL's. Eg. query batches or lazy loading.

NHibernate is quite light-weight compared to other ORM's and compared to it's powerful features.

NHibernate (as any other ORM) could be considered to be overkill if there is no object oriented business model but you need to optimize for highest performance. I don't think that Google could make use of NHibernate for its search engine, for instance.

---

**Edit:**

The performance and power of NHibernate is not fully for free. It requires that the developers understand at least the basics about relational databases. Other ORM's try to hide the whole relational problematics, which leads to much more unoptimized behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

nHibernate is a professional joke.
In my company, its use has been prohibited by several reasons.
As tool is quite unproductive; you'll spend countless hours trying to figure out, or finding alternate strategies in a scarce documentation.

Much better, use your own generated DAL and SP's to achieve high performance. You'll have a cached execution plan, and in the end that's what really matters.

nHibernate has no advanced support for memcached, which is specially what you are going to use  if you want to build a scalable web solution, like Facebook.

I work for a social gaming company, and we have specially forbidden to use nhibernate in particular.

Comment: Yes, NHibernate can be a dangerous tool in the hands of bad developers.

Comment: Yes, indeed nHibernate is hard to use, and companies are starting to abandon it in favor of new alternatives such as Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate supports query caching, 2nd level caching based on primary keys, and also session cache for repeated hits on the same entity within the same session.

That's all a great help, but as long as you are hitting a database with a large load, you are going to have scaling problems. The best way to scale a database is to minimise the amount of time you actually have to use it. Distributed cache such as memcache, and caching your output (either post-datacrunched views or html) are the best ways to scale an application. If clients are regularly hitting the database, you are doing it wrong, ORM or not. In a .NET application, like a typical MVC app, has the advantages of being able to use varyby output caching, donut and donut-hole caching, as well as clients for memcache to be used with NHibernate and for your ViewModels.